# How do I re-arrange a char array according to another sequence (which is a float array sorted in ascending order)?

Tags: c

For an assignment, I've been tasked with creating a Polyclinic Patient Attendance viewer. I have been given the following data: Percentage attendance for 4 different cases for a given year. For the project, we have to complete 5 functions. I've got 4 down but I still can't get my head around 1. According to the question, I have to display "The lowest to the highest percentage of case and name of the case for the year". I understand bubble sorting and I am able to arrange the percentages in ascending order. What I struggle to do however is display the names of the cases according to that ascending order I can get.

I tried to create a 2D char array which includes the names of the 4 cases and also a float array with the percentages. Then included in the "swapping" portion of the sorting algorithm, I tried to do swapping with the char array as well.

```
float year2010Cases[4] = { 11.2,8.9,15.6,15.9 };
char  caseName[4][28] = { "Respiratory Tract Infection", "Diabetes 
Mellitus","Hyperlipidemia","Hypertensive Disease" };
char swap[1][28];

#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{

    int c, d;
    float temp;
    char swap[1][28];


    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < 3 - c; d++)
        {
            if (year2010Cases[d] > year2010Cases[d + 1]) 
            {
                temp = year2010Cases[d];
                year2010Cases[d] = year2010Cases[d + 1];
                year2010Cases[d + 1] = temp;

                swap[1][28] = caseName[d][28];
                caseName[d][28] = caseName[d + 1][28];
                caseName[d + 1][28] = swap[1][28];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        printf("%.1f\n", year2010Cases[c]);

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        printf("%s \n", caseName[c][28]);
}
```

I expected the case names to be displayed in the same order as the percentages as they are swapping at the same time as the percentages swapped. However, for my actual results, it does not display anything at all below the second "Sorted list in ascending order:\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap strings you need `strcpy()` (prototype in `<string.h>`)

```
            //swap[1][28] = caseName[d][28];
            //caseName[d][28] = caseName[d + 1][28];
            //caseName[d + 1][28] = swap[1][28];
            strcpy(swap[0], caseName[d]);
            strcpy(caseName[d], caseName[d + 1]);
            strcpy(caseName[d + 1], swap[0]);
```

Also note that `swap[1]` as well as `casename[j][28]` do not exist.

---

Let me add a suggestion (a bit too long for a comment): sort the indexes instead.

```
int indexes[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
// sort indexes <== YOUR TASK
// indexes now is { 1, 0, 2, 3 }
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%f for %s\n", year2010Cases[indexes[i]], caseName[indexes[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The moment I read sort the indexes, it hit me like a truck. Works like a charm. Will try out the strcopy method separately just for my own learning because i've never seen that before nor used <string.h> for my lessons.

Answer (score 0):

When you have data like two different values that "belongs together", you don't put them in two different arrays. Instead you make a `struct` that can hold both values. After that you make an `array of the struct`. Like:

```
// Define a type to hold both percentage and name
typedef struct
{
    float percentage;
    char  caseName[28];
} CaseType;

// In some function make the array
CaseType year2010Cases[4] = {
    {11.2, "Respiratory Tract Infection"},
    {8.9, "Diabetes Mellitus"},
    {15.6, "Hyperlipidemia"},
    {15.9, "Hypertensive Disease"}};
```

One benefit of this is that the two values that belongs together always stays together. Another benefit is that we can use standard `qsort` for sorting data. Like:

```
typedef struct
{
    float percentage;
    char  caseName[28];
} CaseType;


// Compare function used by qsort
int compar(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    CaseType* pa =  (CaseType*)a;
    CaseType* pb =  (CaseType*)b;
    if (pa->percentage > pb->percentage) return 1;
    if (pa->percentage < pb->percentage) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    CaseType year2010Cases[4] = {
        {11.2, "Respiratory Tract Infection"},
        {8.9, "Diabetes Mellitus"},
        {15.6, "Hyperlipidemia"},
        {15.9, "Hypertensive Disease"}};
        printf("Original list:\n");

    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        printf("%.1f - %s\n", year2010Cases[c].percentage, year2010Cases[c].caseName);

    // Sort the array with a single call of qsort
    qsort(year2010Cases, 4, sizeof *year2010Cases, compar);

    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Sorted list:\n");

    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        printf("%.1f - %s\n", year2010Cases[c].percentage, year2010Cases[c].caseName);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original list:
11.2 - Respiratory Tract Infection
8.9 - Diabetes Mellitus
15.6 - Hyperlipidemia
15.9 - Hypertensive Disease
-------------------------------------
Sorted list:
8.9 - Diabetes Mellitus
11.2 - Respiratory Tract Infection
15.6 - Hyperlipidemia
15.9 - Hypertensive Disease
```